# Proof that a subset of metric space with euclidian norm is open iff the same subset is open in metric space with Manhattan norm

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

For $\mathbb{R}^2$ we have the euclidian norm
$$(x_1,x_2)\mapsto\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2},$$
and the Manhattan norm
$$(x_1,x_2)\mapsto|x_1|+|x_2|.$$
Let $d_E$ and $d_M$ be the metrics defined by these norms, respectively. Then we define $B_\epsilon^E(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2|d_E(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ and $B_\epsilon^M(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^2|d_M(x,y)<\epsilon\}$.

> 1 How do I prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta^E(x)\subseteq B_\epsilon^M(x)$?
>   2 How do I prove that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B_\delta^M(x)\subseteq B_\epsilon^E(x)$?
>   3 How do I use these to prove that $Y\subseteq\mathbb{x}^2$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_E)$ iff $Y$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_M)$?

What I have done:
I know that $||x||_E\leq||x||_M\leq\sqrt{2}||x||_E$. So I thought I can take $\delta=\epsilon$ for 1, and $\delta=1/\sqrt{2}$ for 2. But I'm not sure about this.
For 3 I thought: if $Y$ is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_E)$, then it is open in $(\mathbb{R}^2,d_M)$, because of 1 and vice versa. Again, not entirely sure.

Comment: You're on the right track. For (3) -- Use the definition of an open set - i.e. There exists an open ball contained inside the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll use that $\|{\bf x}\|_E \leq \|{\bf x}\|_M \leq \sqrt{2}\|{\bf x}\|_E$, as you correctly noticed. These inequalities give: $$B^E_{\epsilon/\sqrt{2}}({\bf x})\subseteq B^M_\epsilon({\bf x}), \qquad B^M_\epsilon({\bf x}) \subseteq B^E_\epsilon({\bf x}), \quad \forall\,\epsilon >0, \,\forall\,{\bf x}\in \Bbb R^2$$as you can check by thinking geometrically:

[image]

For $(3)$, suppose that $U$ is $E$-open - we'll check that it is $M$-open. Let ${\bf x} \in U$. By $E$-openness, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B^E_\epsilon({\bf x})\subseteq U$. Then, by anterior work, $B^M_\epsilon({\bf x})\subseteq U$. Then $U$ is $M$-open.

You do the same thing to check that every $M$-open set is $E$-open.

Answer (score 0):

Draw some pictures showing what the balls look like. Observe that, given a diamond-shaped "ball", you can always draw a circle inside it. Similarly, given a circle, you can always draw a diamond shape inside it.

For parts (1) and (2), your reasoning is correct. You can see this by looking at the pictures I recommended.

A hint for part (3): use the defintion of "open". The key is being able to find open balls around points of the set.

So suppose a set $Y$ is $E$-open, and we want to show that it's $M$-open. So, for each point $y \in Y$, we need to find an open $M$-ball $B_M$ with $y \in B_M \subset Y$. But, since $Y$ is $E$-open, we can find an open $E$-ball, $B_E$ such that $y \in B_E \subset Y$. Use the result from (1) to find $B_E \subset B_M$.

Comment: You can look at [thsi wiki areticle](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Equivalence_of_metrics&oldid=680875572) to find out some proprties you get from proving $(1)$ and $(2)$